# Error when webscraping news from cnn using selenium and bs4 to get links and titles from articles

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I wrote this code for now to webscrape news from a spacific topic from cnn:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

serch_term = input('What News are you looking for today? ')

service = Service(executable_path='chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)
driver.get(f'https://edition.cnn.com/search?q={serch_term}')

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,'html.parser' )
soup.select('h3.cnn-search__result-headline')
```

But its not working im getting this error after chrome pops up with the cnn site

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:65095/devtools/browser/05c3af16-cb5a-423c-af0b-c6cc96af980d
[11496:15920:0314/183947.010:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(995)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -200
PS C:\Users\user\Desktop\Informatik\Praktik\Projekte\Python\stiil_working_on\news_automation> [3408:22012:0314/183950.356:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [18:39:50.360] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1049 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: Ein an das System angeschlossenes Ger�t funktioniert nicht. (0x1F)
[3408:22012:0314/183950.356:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [18:39:50.362] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1049 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: Ein an das System angeschlossenes Ger�t funktioniert nicht. (0x1F)
[11496:15920:0314/183953.096:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(995)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -200
[15208:11512:0314/184146.206:ERROR:gpu_init.cc(440)] Passthrough is not supported, GL is disabled, ANGLE is
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

input fuction can't find search result and it raises error but general search is working. Please Just run the code.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

serch_term = 'News'

url = f'https://edition.cnn.com/search?q={serch_term}'
print(url)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.maximize_window()

driver.get(url)
time.sleep(4)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
#driver.close()

for h3 in soup.select('h3.cnn-search__result-headline > a'):
    title=h3.text
    url=h3.get('href')
    abs_url='https:'+ url
    print(abs_url)
```

Output:

```
https://www.cnn.com/europe/live-news/ukraine-russia-putin-news-03-14-22/index.html
https://www.cnn.com/2022/03/14/energy/india-russia-oil/index.html
https://www.cnn.com/2022/03/14/us/new-york-city-washington-dc-homeless-shootings/index.html
https://www.cnn.com/2022/03/14/politics/breonna-taylor-mother-federal-charges-officers/index.html
https://www.cnn.com/2022/03/14/politics/biden-possible-european-trip/index.html
https://www.cnn.com/2022/03/07/world/what-we-know-brittney-griner-arrest-russia/index.html
https://www.cnn.com/2022/03/14/middleeast/mideast-summary-03-14-2022-intl/index.html
https://www.cnn.com/2022/03/14/energy/oil-prices/index.html
https://www.cnn.com/2022/03/14/tech/pete-davidson-blue-origin-launch-scn/index.html
https://www.cnn.com/2022/03/14/politics/donald-trump-south-carolina-speech/index.html
```

Comment: how do i get the the text in a not href ? @F.Hoque

Comment: @Noam Kramer,just h3.text

Comment: did it can u tell me now pls?

Comment: See update,@Noam Kramer

Comment: @Noam Kramer , I've updated again

Comment: now i wnat to webscrape the articles how do i give each link from abs_link a variable or some to driver.get the exact article